# Uncaught TypeError: this.props.getData is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux

Not able to call function inside a component, provided by Redux.

This is my Container component

```
export class HomeContainer extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <Home 
                getData={ this.props.getData }
            />
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return state;
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return bindActionCreators({
        getData: getCountriesList.getCountriesByISO
    }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomeContainer);
```

I am calling that redux function inside the component using

```
componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getData();
    }
```

This is my Action

```
export function getCountriesByISOData() {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(toggleLoading(true));
        return fetch('/api/countries', {
            method: 'GET',
        }).then(res => {
            if(res.status === 200) {
                return res.json().then(res=> {
                    console.log(res)
                    dispatch(toggleLoading(false));
                    dispatch(isSuccess(res));
                })
            } else {
                dispatch(toggleLoading(false));
                dispatch(isError(res.statusText));
            }
        }).catch(error => {
            dispatch(toggleLoading(false));
            dispatch(isError(error));
        })
    }
}
```

and this is my reducer

```
let defaultState = {
    isLoading: false,
    data: [],
    error: ''
}

const getCountriesByISOReducer = (state=defaultState, action) => {
    if(action.type === 'COUNTRIES_ISO_TOGGLE_LOADING') {
        return {
            ...state,
            isLoading: action.isLoading
        }
    }
    if(action.type === 'COUNTRIES_ISO_IS_ERROR') {
        return {
            ...state,
            error: action.error
        }
    }
    if(action.type === 'COUNTRIES_ISO_IS_SUCCESS') {
        return {
            ...state,
            data: [...state.data, action.success]
        }
    }
    return state;
}

export default getCountriesByISOReducer;
```

This is my root reducer

```
export default combineReducers({
    globalConfirmedCases: globalConfirmedCasesReducer,
    dailyStatsByDate: getDailyStatsByDateReducer,
    dailyStats: getDailyStatsReducer,
    getCountriesByISO: getCountriesByISOReducer,
    getCountriesStats: getCountriesStatsReducer
});
```

What I am doing wrong here? Is there any naming conventions while writing reducers and actions and using it in the react context?

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: This is my stack trace,
Uncaught TypeError: this.props.getData is not a function
    at Home.componentDidMount (Home.jsx:18)
    at commitLifeCycles (react-dom.development.js:19814)
    at commitLayoutEffects (react-dom.development.js:22803)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:188)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:237)

Comment: I'm sure there's some problem in `getData` prop in `mapDispatchToProps`. Try to `console.log(this.props.getData)` in your component.

Comment: And make sure you have imported `bindActionCreators` from `redux`.

Comment: I am getting a undefined on this.props.getData. BindActionCreators is imported in my container component.

Comment: Can you post the code containing `getCountriesList`?

Comment: I already posted, its my action function. the name of the module is getCountriesList

Comment: To access the data: you'd have to use `getCountriesList.getCountriesByISO.data` if  you have your slice reducer named `getCountriesByISO` in root reducer.

Comment: There is no function called getCountriesList.getCountriesByISO.data. In my container component I am using the functions exported from actions called getCountriesList

Comment: Stil gives me the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213350/discussion-between-metalheaddev-and-jithin-zacharia).